# Earth's Magnetic Field and Rotation used to generate electricity in huge longitudinal coil

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

If we wrapped the Earth in a longitudinal copper coil, would the planet's magnetic field and rotation give current through the coil? Is this the energy solution?

Comment: Where will you gt that amount of copper?

Comment: The coil would be moving with Earth, so d flux / dt = 0, and so no current would be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Would you get any current in your coil? No.
You need to have a change in magnetic flux. Since the coil will move with the Earth, the flux will be constant and change would be zero.

Is this energy solution? No.
Because it doesn't even work in theory. You will just end up wasting all the copper, which we don't even know where to get from. Our planet is not as small as you are imagining.